# Sitecore SXA Navigation Menu is not inline & active loading css aggregate class need to change nav-item class

Tags: sxa

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

I have used Navigation Component where i have existing code in Navigation.cshtml its loading some default aggreagte class I want to change nav-item active class for first menu(default) and other only nav-item after clicking any menu then class change to nav-item active So where need to change.If I change in Navigation.cshtml as nav-item active then it will pick for all list
Also ABOUT US and other menu is not inline it is breaking into two line how to make inline because in inspect mode i applied same code as existing still for me its showing two line.

Comment: Did you try to handle this using a CSS class?

Comment: Actually @SumitBhatia in Navigation.cshtml i used to change nav-tem active with existing aggregate class but this active is appended to all list item not for only home

Comment: Did you change it manually in the OOTB component?

Comment: Actually i have duplicate the Navigation folder in one custom folder after that i applied changes to this class  <li class="@item.CssClasses.Aggregate() @relativeClass"> loadind as class="level1 item0 odd first rel-level1 no-child" i updated to  nav-item active  because i have no idea where to change this class except this

Comment: I would suggest you use a container component and add a custom CSS class to that. Then add the navigation component and then use your class that you added in a container to perform navigation components. Use this for your reference. https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/01/27/sitecore-sxa-using-sxa-styles-feature/

Comment: Actually @SumitBhatia  I did this i have created new styles and assigned to navigation but in list class it is not appending nav-item class

Comment: Can you try the above that I mentioned to use a container component first and then add navigation under that. Add you css to Container component and then it will work as a outer CSS class to apply CSS on child components.